# Duplicate target in Xcode get error: Xcode cannot run using the selected device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, targets

I duplicate a target, create and link a new Info.plist file, a prefix.pch file, also change bundle ID and bundle name. Build is ok, but got message:

Xcode cannot run using the selected device.
Choose a destination with a supported architecture in order to run on this device.

what ever in simulator or in iPod, it can not run.

What can I do? Is it because the reason of bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changed *Product name* in Build setting, it can be run.